# How to call ngOnInit() again in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

Please explain in this code, how to call `ngOnInit()` again when I call another method?

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    this.model = this.userData;
  });
}

update() {
  this.loading = true;
  this.userService.update(this.model).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      alert('Update successful');
    },
    (error) => {
      alert('Not updated');
      this.loading = false;
    },
  );
  this.user_data();
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose? Just move the code to another method and call that method from `ngOnInit()`. `ngOnInit()` is called once for every method. There is no way to make it being called multiple times.

Comment: please explain me for updated code

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are two options from my point of view:

> **Calling ngOnInit() from another function scope**. But I would suggest to do not adopt this approach given `ngOnInit`[is an angular core method that belongs to OnInit Interface](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit).

```js
    public ngOnInit() {
          this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
          this.model=this.userData;
      });      
    }
    
    update() {
           this.ngOnInit();
    }
```

> Break your functionality into another function, use `ngOnInit`to call it and, afterwards, any  request can be made from anywhere by calling the function in the following manner: `this.<MethodName>();`.

```js
    public ngOnInit() {
          this.getRouteData();
    }
    
    update() {
           this.getRouteData(); 
    }

    getRouteData() {
      this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
          this.model=this.userData;
      }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

If the purpose is to trigger `ngOnInit()` when query param is updated, then do following:

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for. Big thank you Hari

Comment: But this will affect if you have `routerLink` to go in other routes it will not work.
Tested by myself

Answer (score 4):

`ngOnInit` called once the component is created. so you can create a function and call the function again. Here is the sample code.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.callFun();
}    

update() {
    this.callFun();
    // do code
}

private callFun(){
   // do code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not need to call ngOnInit again. So the question remains, what are you really trying to accomplish? Are you having issues retrieving the routing parameter?

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
      this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.model=this.userData;
  });
```

Your code within the subscribe above will *AUTOMATICALLY* be re-executed every time the route parameters change. So there is no need to manually call ngOnInit again.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a function ...

```
ngOnInit() {}

secondMethod() { this.ngOnInit(); }
```

I've been doing it all the time to reload my data, never had a problem with it.

Comment: you should not call ngOnInit life cycle from another custom function

Comment: @Mdomerarafat Could you explain why not?