# How to refresh only a part of a component without refreshing ngOnInIt() in angular?

Tags: angular

I need to know whether there is a way to refresh only the delete reply part without refreshing the whole component with ngOnInIt()

```
 public deleteReply(commentId, replyId) {
    this.isLoadingReplyDelete = true;
    this.discussionService.deleteReply(commentId, replyId).takeWhile(() => this.alive)
      .subscribe(returnObj => {
     if (returnObj.status === 200) {
      this.isLoadingReplyDelete = false;
      this.ngOnInit();
    }
   });
  }
 }
```

Comment: const index = this.listData.data.indexOf(key);
     this.listData.data.splice(index, 1); and then you can call refreshing get data api method..

Comment: If part of a component can b refreshed on its own, it should then be a child component of the current one.

Comment: Take a look about change detector in angular 
https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef
and take a look also on this article 
https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `ngOnInit()` from another function's scope, [it is part of `@angular/core`](http://https//angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44943103/9766768

You will need to provide some context (e.g. your template code) see you which implementation of [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) would be good practice in this case, but other comments have pointed you in the right direction.